# VSTS setting up Visual Studio Build task to do what command line does

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-devops

We can't seem to get a self contained .exe to be built using the Visual Studio Build task of VSTS. The code we typically would use for publishing manually on a local computer with a .exe availabe:

```
dotnet publish -c release -r win7-x64
```

In VSTS I found that I can set $(BuildPlatform) to x64, but I don't know how to setup the configuration for the Visual Studio Build task that would duplicate that command line.

Comment: Are you using the dotnet build task or calling the command line? The dotnet build task has an arguments option, can't you put `-c release -r win7-x64` in there?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding configuration for Visual Studio Build Task, you can specify it in **Configuration** input box directly:

[image]

Regarding Visual Studio Build task does for dotnet publish command line, you can specify RuntimeIdentifier and targer arguments in MSBuild Arguments, simple steps:

1. Add a variable to build definition, for example: `runtime` `win7-x64`
2. Add .Net Core Restore task (Arguments: `-r $(runtime)`)
3. Add Visual Studio Build task (MSBuild Arguments: `/p:RuntimeIdentifier=$(runtime) /t:publish`), check above screenshot.

On the other hand, there is .Net Core Publish task that could does it:

[image]